# HTML 5, History.js and Jquery .load() implementation

Tags: jquery, html, history.js

I am trying to teach myself how to use HTML5 hisory api and jquery to create a web app.
I am loading the contents of a page into a div but when I try to go back or forward, nothing happens. Below is the code

```
$(document).on('click',".ul_links",function(e){


      loader_img();

      var teamid = $(this).attr('id');
      var href = '/Myapp/Pages/FundingSourceView.php?teamid='+teamid;




      $('#midpanel').load(href,function(response,status,xhr){         
          if(status=='error')
          {
              alert('An error occured. Contact admin. Specific error is '+ xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);

          }
          });


           var currentState = history.state;          
           History.pushState(currentState,'',href);

           e.preventDefault();
          return false

      });
```

I am using the History.js plugin and I am having some difficulty implementing this feature.

I get 404 errors if the variable href is not absolute. When href is absolute, the link works but I cannot use the forward or back buttons to load the previous contents
All help greatly appreciated.